# Why TestEntityManager puts data at id 0 in h2 in memory database?

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I was trying to test findById(1) of Jpa Repository. But it was returning empty. When I used 0 for id , it returned the right object.

Why the TestEntityManager saves the data in h2 in-memory database at index 0 by default?

Comment: What strategy were you using for GeneratedValue in your Entity class

Comment: GenerationType.IDENTITY